# Gradient Decent for Linear Regression (Machine Learning week 1 by Ng Andrew)

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, linear-gradients, gradient-descent, calculus

I'm trying to understand the Gradient descent algorithm for linear regression.

The question is why we multiply by x(1) at the end of theta1 and don't do that at the end of theta0?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hypothesis is `theta0 + theta1*x`. On differentiating with respect to `theta0` and `theta1` you get `1` and `x` respectively. So, you get `x` in update for `theta1` but not for `theta0`. For more details, refer to this document, [cs229-notes1](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf).

Comment: In the notes, Andrew uses the generalized form, but he writes "To simplify our notation, we also introduce the convention of letting `x_0 = 1` (this is the intercept term)" to be clear.

Comment: OP is asking about the specific case where `x_0 = 1 and x_1 = x`, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I know; and that was the reason for my comment above. The OP might need a little bit of help when going over the notes.

Answer (score 0):

In short because of partial derivative & Application of the chain rule.

For Theta 0, when you take derivative of the loss function (MSE) with respect to Theta 0 (Or Beta 0 / Intercept ), your derivative is in the form shown the rightmost of eq1.

```
imagine...
Y = Mx + C
M = Theta 1
C = Theta 0

Loss Function = (Y - (Mx + C))^2

The derivative is in the form of f(x) * f'(x) if that makes sense. f'(x) in Theta 0 is 1 (watch the video to understand the derivate). So

2(Y - (Mx + C)) *  derivative of with respect to C of (Y - (Mx + C))
= 2(Y - (Mx + C)) [disregard the 2 in front]


For Theta 1, when you take derivative of the loss function (MSE) with respect to Theta 1 (Or Beta 1 / slope ), your derivative is in the form shown the rightmost of eq1. In this case f'(x) is x, because.....

2(Y - (Mx + C)) *  derivative of with respect to M of (Y - (Mx + C))
= 2(Y - (Mx + C)) * (1*x) [because the only term that is left is dx(Mx)]
```

Here is a video that can help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDv4f4s2SB8

Answer (score 0):

The loss function for linear regression is given by

```
J = {(HthetaX(i))-y}^2
```

And we have gradient = Derivative of Loss.Therefore,

`DJ/Dtheta = 2*(HthetaX(i))-y)*X(i)`. Now for `theta0 X(i) ==1` ,hence

```
DJ/Dtheta for Theta0 = 2*(Htheta*X(i))-y)
```